# How to set a NULL column value through an ADO query connected to a MySQL ODBC source in C++?

Tags: c++, mysql, c++builder, ado, vcl

Given a given MySQL table

```
DESC tabl_foo;
--------------------------------
Field            Type         Null    Key    Default    Extra
-----------------------------------------------------------------
fooId            varchar(15)  NO      PRI    NULL
FooDate          date         YES     MUL    NULL
```

I need to update `FooDate` for a given row. So I tried this code :

```
query->SQL->Add("UPDATE tbl_foo SET FooDate = :FooDate WHERE fooId = :id"):

// both arguments are AnsiString
query->Parameters->FindParam("id")->Value = FoodId;
query->Parameters->FindParam("FooDate")->Value = FooDate; 

query->ExecSQL();
```

However, this fails

> Incorrect date value: "" for folumn `FooDate` at row 1

It turns out that `FooDate` may be an empty string (or `{ data:NULL }`), and MySQL does not like that. So, I tried setting `Null()` :

```
if (FooDate.IsEmpty())
   query->Parameters->FindParam("FooDate")->Value = Null();
else
   query->Parameters->FindParam("FooDate")->Value = FooDate;
```

But then I get this error :

> Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided.

What should be the value to set for MySQL `NULL`?

Comment: use a date like '9999-01-01' Null in date is always complictaed

Comment: Just to check - are you `Clear()`'ing the `SQL` each time? Do you have the same problem if you replace `query->SQL->Add("UPDATE ...");` with `query->SQL->Text = "UPDATE ...";`?

Comment: Have you tried using [`Unassigned()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Variants.Unassigned) instead of `Null()`?

Comment: Would try ...FindParam("FooDate")->Value = "NULL";

Comment: @Baxter That will assign a string value `"NULL"`, not a true `NULL`. That will fail if the column does not support strings

Comment: @Remy Ahh, the parameters maybe a problem. So another way to do it would be using a different update statement depending on whether foodate is null. So if foodate is null then use - 

    query->SQL->Add("UPDATE tbl_foo SET FooDate = NULL WHERE fooId = :id")

Answer (score 0):

To make the update the system needs to know the types of the parameters.  It can deduce the type from the variant you apply, and MySQL can do certain conversions for you, but it's always best to specify the data type.

So what you would need is something like:

```cpp
  if((pParam=query->Parameters->FindParam("FooDate"))!=NULL)
  {
    pParam->DataType=ftDate;
    if(FooDate.IsEmpty())
    {
      pParam->Value=Null();
    }
    else
    {
      pParam->Value=FooDate;
    }
  }
```

You may want to look at keeping FooDate as a TDateTime, but you will need to detect NULL dates properly.